# Github Visual Studio Extension indentations don't work for VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, github

I'm new to programming and just recently started using Github to work on my code with other people. I have installed the Github extension onto Visual Studio 2017 and now every time I press enter it moves me to either a random line or doesn' work at all. Also, the debugger now takes a long time to process and give me errors. I am currently running on Windows 10 with the latest version of VS.

Comment: I haven't installed that extension myself but it seems hard to believe that that's normal so I'd suggest uninstalling it and see if things go back to normal, then try installing again after a restart.

Comment: @jmcilhinney just tried that and it works without the extension but when I installed it back again the indentations were still broken